# Object vs Android Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a time-sheet app for myself that I can use at work. I've pasted the code for my two classes below. My conundrum is not having to pass or keep data just how to go back to the original view if I've opened a canvas object. Is it possible to use an intent to open an activity rather than just creating the "tv" object (in openTEV method)? That would mean that when I tap the "back" button on the bottom right of my Galaxy phone it will stop that activity and go back to the first one with the EditText objects that I've entered strings into. At the moment hitting the back button ends the entire app. Or am I misunderstanding how android works?

MainActivity.java -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MyTouchEventView tv;
private EditText et1;
private EditText et2;
private EditText et3;
private EditText et4;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    et4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
}

public void processForm(View v) {
    String txt = et1.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i("TAG", "Paused");
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_save:
            saveCanvasImage();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_sign:
            openTEV();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void saveCanvasImage() {

    tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bm = tv.getDrawingCache();

    String fPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    fPath = fPath + "/Pictures";
    File f = null;
    String s = getCurrDate();
    s = s + ".png";
    f = new File(fPath, s);

    try {
    FileOutputStream strm = new FileOutputStream(f);
    bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, strm);
    strm.flush();
    strm.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void openTEV() {

    tv = new MyTouchEventView(this);
    setContentView(tv);
    addContentView(tv.btnReset, tv.params);

}

public String getCurrDate()
{
    String dt;
    Date dNow = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddkkmmss");
    dt = sdf.format(dNow);

    return dt;
}
```

MyTouchEventView.java -

```
public class MyTouchEventView extends View {

private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();

public Button btnReset;
public LayoutParams params;

public MyTouchEventView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10f);

    btnReset = new Button(context);
    btnReset.setText("Clear Screen");

    params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btnReset.setLayoutParams(params);

    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // resets the screen
            path.reset();

            // Calls the onDraw() method
            postInvalidate();

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    // Gives you x and y coordinates on the Event.
    float pointX = event.getX();
    float pointY = event.getY();

    // Checks for the event that occurs
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        //;
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }

    // Schedules a repaint.
    // Force a view to draw.
    postInvalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: you have two activities or one ?

Comment: I believe that I have one at the moment (MainActivity). When I create an object for MyTouchEventView I'm assuming this doesn't create an activity. My question is how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you want to open a new activity from your **openTEV** method...am I right??? to achieve this, first of all you have the activity that you want to start from activity.

Suppose, you have two activities which are **MainActivity** and **BActivity**. Now, you want, when **openTEV** metod will be executed then **BActivity** should start from **MainActivity**. Now what you have to do is to write the following code into your **openTEV** method...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now when you will press back button in **BActivity** then you will return **MainActivity**.

Comment: I just tried replacing the code in my openTEV() method with the two lines above to create a new activity with an intent. It's causing my app to close. I'm getting "FATAL EXCEPTION: main" in the LogCat. I've just realised I'll probably have to make a layout file to go with the new activity. Now I have no idea what sort of view to put in the XML file. Do I need a view at all in the second layout file?

Comment: yeah...you need an activity with a layout. For this, press the **New** icon at top-left corner then a window will appear...select **Android Activity**...press **Next**...then **Next**...then give your new activity name...then press **Finish**...Now you have created a new activity. Now you can start your new Activity from **MainActivity** through the above process as I mentioned.

Comment: I've created a new activity as per your instructions. But I've spent half an hour trying associate the MyTouchEventView with it so it has the canvas. I don't think I've even come close. How do I do this?

Comment: follow the way to associates the MyTouchEventView with your second activity as you already have done with MainActivity.

Comment: I don't see how that can work. When I created a new activity it created a new layout file, activity_brush.xml. To do what I had in MainActivity I would have to delete he line setContentView(R.layout.activity_brush) in onCreate and replace it with setContentView(tv). Surely I have to leave the setContentView created by the activity wizard. What;s throwing me out here is that I have three classes. MainActivity, BrushActivity, MyTouchEventView (which extends View). I just have no idea how to use MyTouchEventView from an activity.

Comment: See the last link in my answer, or, you could just do what you already do, `tv = new MyTouchEventView(this);
 setContentView(tv);` in your new activity

Answer (score 1):

You haven't "opened" your "canvas object".  Your canvas object is a `View`, like any other view e.g. `TextView`, `ImageView`, `EditText` etc.  You have extended the View class to make a new type of view.

Here, you set the contents of your one and only activity to your custom view.

```
 tv = new MyTouchEventView(this);
 setContentView(tv);
```

As you only have one activity, when you press the back button, your app will end - since there are no more activities to display to the user.

To be able to interact with `MyTouchEventView`, create a new activity, set it's content to your view as you do above, then launch the new activity with an `Intent`.  When you press the back button, you will return to your current activity, `MainActivity`.

It is not usual to use `setContentView` more than once in an activity.  Think of an activity as a single, focused thing which the user interacts with - a screen if you like.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

I see that you are creating a button in your view.  This is not correct.  a `View` is the lowest level of interface component.  A `View` cannot contain other views.  To do that, you use a `ViewGroup` such as `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc.  It is also possible to add your custom view to your XML layout so that you do not have to create it in code.  It is normally good practice to separate code and UI.

See this for how to add your view to a layout XML

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Answer (score 0):

Think if i am not wrong, than just make a child activity. While creating a new activity you will get the options for showing one of the activities u already have- as the new activities parent activity. So, in this way you will get a back navigation inaction bar, by which u can easily navigate to ur parent activity from child.
ANd on the mainActivity(parent) just use intent to go to ur child activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BActivity.class); //BActivity-the child activity
startActivity(intent);
```